# Android Fragment: Fragment should manage itself being shown/deleted

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dynamic-ui

it is me again and i first wanted to apologize for asking that much today.

Here is my situation.
Because of my design my FragmentActivity( topmost parent in obiect hierarchy) has only one member, which for itself has a collection of objects like fragments,  i have one level between fragmentactivity and the fragments. I would like to avoid some kind of event bus and/or observable pattern to pass the events of the fragments buttons to my object which would forward them to fragment activity to be then handled there.

Especially showing fragment, deleting replacing fragments is preferred to be handled in my object in between or even in the fragment itself.

Is this recommended? Or will I get into any trouble?

Comment: Wait so you have an "object" between your activity and the fragment? How so? I'm confused by your question. If all you need to do is connect the fragment back to the host activity you can use an interface for that. To go activity to fragment, just get a reference to the fragment and call any public method.

Comment: Mainly the object in between,called controller shall handle EVERYTHING. The fragment activity instantiates this object and thats it. And i want to avoid doing anything else in fragmentactivity.

Comment: Then what are your fragments actually loaded into? There has to either be a fragment transaction or some other structure like a ViewPager that is holding them.

Comment: I use the fragment transaction and fragment manager approach,until now by passing activity reference to my controller( what i read can cause memory leaks, creates unnice crossreference and should be avoided ).

Comment: I would stay away from using an intermediate controller. You're trying to optimize and already optimized process.

Comment: No, I try to adopt and port a code to java.
With most keeping it identical to original source code, where ever.